# How do I create a Windows 10 account for network shares, but not local login?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, user-accounts

I need to share a folder on my network for my new scanner to save documents to. I don't want to give the scanner my personal account's password, and it looks like anonymous shares, even very limited ones, are a bad idea now (correct me if I'm wrong!). So I thought I'd make a dedicated username / password for the scanner, but don't want to show it on the user switching screen. Is this possible?

ETA: I got it off the user switching screen.  Does this mean that no local login is *ever* possible using this account?  Ideally it would be valid only as a network credential...

Comment: You probably want to look into the Deny Local Logon user policy. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957048.aspx

Comment: Should have specified this is the Home edition. No Group Policy :-/

Comment: Have you tried the existing answers for Windows 7 yet?  If so, exactly which did you try and what were the results?  [How to hide admin account and only show main user at logon screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/278219/how-to-hide-admin-account-and-only-show-main-user-at-logon-screen-in-windows-7), [Hide account from login screen but can be used in UAC](http://superuser.com/questions/66400/hide-account-from-login-screen-but-can-be-used-in-uac), [Hide user from login screen without deactivating it](http://superuser.com/questions/236755/hide-user-from-login-screen-without-deactivating-it)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I had actually done the first one once already for a different "service" account and forgotten about it.  ::sigh::  Thanks for the reminder... :D

Comment: Did you try to just disable the 'share' account?